# React Navigation Header Is always shown

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to create multiple screens and to switch between them I thought react-navigation  would be great. But I am getting this problem of header appearing automatically, despite setting header to null. 
I have my App.js createStackNavigation as :

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({


register : {
  screen: RegisterScreen, 
},

login: {
  screen: LoginScreen,
},

home : {
  screen: HomeScreen
},

  },

  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header:null,
      headerMode: 'none',
    }
  }
  );
```

Here I have three screens. Namely register , login and home. Inside register screen I have other createStackNavigator for registerFinal, login and register screen itself. It is shown below.

```
const registerNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
        register: {
            screen: RegisterScreen,
            headerMode: 'none',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
              }),
        }, 
        registerFinal: {
            screen: RegisterFinalScreen, 
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerShown: false

              }),
        } ,
        login: {
            screen: LoginScreen, 
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerShown: false
              }),
        },
    },

    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: null,
            headerShown: false
          }),
    }
    );
```

Though, I have header disabled in navigationOptions using both methods as specified in other questions, none of them seems to work for me. I am getting two header in my screen. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the emulator solved the problem. OMG. This thing had me change my project so many times. But sometimes, you just have to laugh at it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of hiding Headers are:

```
export default class LoginPage extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = { // remove header on this page
      header: null
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that. But the problem was, it works only for one stacknavigator. I used same screen in 2 stacknavigator, so it showed two headers. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

Use `headerMode` not `headerShown` on the registeration stack as well.

Basically change your registeration stack to reflect the following:

```
const registerNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
        register: {
            screen: RegisterScreen,
            headerMode: 'none',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
            }),
        },
        registerFinal: {
            screen: RegisterFinalScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerMode: 'none'

            }),
        },
        login: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerMode: 'none'
            }),
        },
    },

    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: null,
            headerMode: 'none'
        }),
    }
);const registerNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
        register: {
            screen: RegisterScreen,
            headerMode: 'none',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
            }),
        },
        registerFinal: {
            screen: RegisterFinalScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerMode: 'none'

            }),
        },
        login: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                headerMode: 'none'
            }),
        },
    },

    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: null,
            headerMode: 'none'
        }),
    }
);
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

`headerMode: 'none'` should not be inside `navigationOptions`:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 // ...
}, {
  // No `navigationOptions` here
  headerMode: 'none'
})
```

Comment: In V4x we use `static` in any component to do any option like `headerShown:false` Now in V5 How can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

## Most of the times you will need to restart `EXPO` or `RN cli` in order for Simulator to take the change.

---

### This is how you hide the header on one screen

```js
`yourComponentName`.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        headerShown: false
    }
}

//above code needs to be before you EXPORT your component

export default `yourComponentName`
```

You could also hide `header` on all screens, check like this.

Tip: instead of adding `headerShown: false` to each screen’s option, you can add `screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}` to the navigator to set the option for all of the screens.

[https://medium.com/@satya164/tip-instead-of-adding-headershown-false-to-each-screens-option-you-can-padd-screenoptions-f67baf1e1eae][1]](https://medium.com/@satya164/tip-instead-of-adding-headershown-false-to-each-screens-option-you-can-padd-screenoptions-f67baf1e1eae%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Create one object as below

```
const screenOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
};
```

And then use options like I used below

```
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  >
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={screenOptions} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Following this will not show component name when called.

Final version will look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './screens/Home';

export default function RootNavigation() {
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const screenOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
};

return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  >
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={screenOptions} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```